# How to verify the result of a console application in healthcheck of docker compose?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I am using the following docker-compose file to run 3 projects.

1. my api application
2. a conosole application to do db migrations
3. a test project to run unit tests.

All of them are in the same solution and hence uses same docker file.
I want to ensure that the test project is run only after the successful completion of migration project. How can I add a health check to the console application ( **myserver-migrations**) in the docker compose file?
For now I just added

```
depends_on:
      - myserver-migration
```

But this won't guarantee that the migration has succeeded. Is there any way to set some state inside console application and read it in the other (unit test) container?

```
services:
  myserver:
    container_name: myserver
    ports:
      - "3434:80"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: test
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost/health"]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 1
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
  myserver-migration:
    container_name: myserver-migration
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: build    
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      myserver:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: 'dotnet run -p MyServer.Migrations resetdb true'
myserver-tests:
container_name: myserver-tests
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  target: build
depends_on:
  - myserver-migration

command: 'dotnet test MyServer.sln'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using `service_completed_successfully` flag in condition.

```
myserver-tests:
container_name: myserver-tests
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  target: build
depends_on:
  myserver-migration:
    condition: service_completed_successfully
```

`service_completed_successfully` ensure that the exit code of  the dependent container is 0.  So I modified the console application to return 0 if everything executes as planned.